# How to fix " '$event' is defined but never used no-unused-vars"

Tags: vue.js, apache-poi

I'm working on vue with poi config , and want to resolve errors like "

> WebpackError at /
>               ModuleError in
>               Module Error (from ./node_modules/eslint-loader/index.js):
>              C:\xampp\htdocs\poc\components-master\es\index.js
>        85:26  error  '$event' is defined but never used     no-unused-vars"

without eslintconfig where i linked my components in poc via npm link.
Is there any solution?

i have tried eslint --fix but it is not working.

Comment: Post the piece of code generating this error

Comment: You could start by not defining variables that you aren't using

Comment: @YassinHajaj                                                                                                   
           on: {
              mouseleave($event) {
                _vm.open = false;
              },
            },

Comment: @Phil sure will try this.

Comment: @phil  i cant find any other solution. I did it . Its worked. Thanks a lot